# Torch installation failure: "No space left on device"

Tags: torch, tmp

Cannot reinstall most recent **Torch**. Cloning fresh repo and attempting to install via `install.sh` which performs a series of `make` calls results in:

```
[ 75%] Building NVCC (Device) object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/generated/THC_generated_THCTensorMathCompareTDouble.cu.o
[ 76%] Building NVCC (Device) object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/generated/THC_generated_THCTensorMathPointwiseDouble.cu.o
[ 77%] Building NVCC (Device) object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/generated/THC_generated_THCTensorMathCompareDouble.cu.o
[ 78%] Building NVCC (Device) object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/generated/THC_generated_THCTensorMathReduceDouble.cu.o
[ 80%] Building NVCC (Device) object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/generated/THC_generated_THCTensorMaskedDouble.cu.o
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h(234) (col. 12): catastrophic error: error while writing generated C++ file: No space left on device

1 catastrophic error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_0001f39b_00000000-5_THCTensorMaskedDouble.cpp4.ii".
Compilation terminated.
fatbinary fatal   : Could not write file '/tmp/tmpxft_0001efb5_00000000-2_THCTensorMathCompareTHalf.fatbin.c'
CMake Error at THC_generated_THCTensorMathCompareTHalf.cu.o.cmake:267 (message):
  Error generating file
  /local/pavels/torch/extra/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/generated/./THC_generated_THCTensorMathCompareTHalf.cu.o
```

There is not enough space on `/tmp` and this is a remote machine so I don't have sudo access to increase it. Is there any workaround for this? Basically what I want to know if there is any way to force `make` store compilation files somewhere not on `/tmp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that I just needed to create `tmp` dir and set it as `TMPDIR` env variable.

```
mkdir $HOME/tmp
export TMPDIR=$HOME/tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `tmp` is.

Sometimes, as an optimization, `tmp` is mounted in a ramdisk. You can take a look at that using `mount` or in `/etc/fstab`.

If this is not the case, then make sure the disk partition where `/tmp` is has enough space, or delete other unused temporary files.

[BleachBit](https://www.bleachbit.org/), packaged in many distros, can help you freeing space.

Comment: In my opinion, this does not provide much to the question, OP has already stated `but I don't have sudo access to increase [ /tmp partition size ]`, so _mount_ / _fstab_ mentions here are irrelevant.

Comment: If he has write privileges for `/tmp` he can delete other `/tmp` files. `BleachBit` does it for you as well.